# How do I make a textbox that only accepts time(hh:mm)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have a textbox in asp .net page .
what javascript/jquery i write for textbox to accept only time(hh:mm format)

i am not interested in using Mask validator

Any help appreciated

Comment: Please, show the code that you have tried so far and explain where you are having trouble.

Comment: @Lance i am naive in javascript ,here i am looking for similar functionality like maskvalidator

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use a regular expression that only allows values in the format '01:01:2013'.
I'm not incredible with regExps but something similar to this would do the trick...

```
var date_check = /[0-9]+ : ([0-9]) + : +[0-9]/;

if(yourtextboxname.value.match(date_check)) 
{
   // whatever you want it to do now...
    return true;
}
else {

    alert("Invalid date");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You'd probably want something more similar to: `var date_check = /^[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}$/` Since the poster wants only hours and minutes (according to post). Would want `{1,2}` rather then `+` because with `+` a value like `123:432` would get through. Also the end of line and beginning of line sentinels so that ONLY that text is matched (though not knowing entirely the behavior of the javascript match function this may not be necessary?)

Comment: Ah I see. Thankyou, that's helpful! Like I said I'm no expert! Thankyou for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

On top of my head this comes across, not sure if that's what you are looking for:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="bdaytime">
```

It is supported by [html5](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_datetime-local) and I find it quite useful except it has too many parameters.

Comment: not much support for it in browsers though http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: Sorry I forgot that there is rest of the world using non-chrome browsers... :P @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ

Answer (score 1):

This is the HTML context:

```
<input type="text" id="field-time" name="timeInput" class="small form-control input-md ng-valid ng-dirty" ng-model="time" placeholder="HH:MM" ng-keypress="validateTimeSlot(time)"/>
```

And this is the JS Angular function:

```
$scope.validateTimeSlot=function (time) {
  var timeSlot = $scope.time;
  var validTimeFormat =  /^(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])$/;
  if(timeSlot == time && angular.isDefined(timeSlot) && !timeSlot.match(validTimeFormat)){
  $scope.error = "Please Enter ' Time' in HH:MM format ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `jQuery`'s plugin `timepicker`: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 0):

There is a masked input JQuery plugin that will handle masking. see http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

`$("#YourTextBox").mask("99:99");`

the masked will validate number only input.you still need javascript code to validate the number by checking if hh and mm falls between  00 and 60

Answer (score 0):

you might wanna take a look at this

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

or you need to build it yourself see:
https://snipt.net/GerryEng/jquery-making-textfield-only-accept-numeric-values/

you would have to add the : tough and the text lenght fix/number validation - i hope you get the idea

regards jan